# How to return key's value of a map of type empty interface

Tags: go, go-map

I have taken a variable like `var u = make(map[string]interface{})` which means that a key could hold a string/int or another map.

When I do the following it gives error `cannot use v (type interface {}) as type string in return argument: need type assertion` which looks obvious as the generic map have no idea what should it search. How can I resolve the issue? The code is given below(DO note that currently, the map is entirely empty)

```
var u = make(map[string]interface{})

// Get function retrieves the value of the given key. If failed, it returns error.
func Get(k string) (string, error) {
    v, found := u[k]
    println(reflect.Type(v))
    if found {
        v = u[k]
        return v, nil
    }
    return v, errors.New(-1)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v, found := u[k]` here v is `interface{}` type

But your function return type is (string, nil) where you are returning (v, nil) or (interface{}, nil).

`interface{}` can not convert into string automatically, need type assertion.

```
data, ok := v.(string)
```

You can return `interface{}` also and the consumer can decide which type it will converted.

Comment: Ah. OK now I got it. Since the map could contain either string or anything, so it is better to return an `interface` and then the consumer of the function should figure out the type of return value whether it is a string, interface or otherwise and use accordingly?

Comment: yes you can return interface{} also and consumer can decide which type it will converted

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's your question. But you're getting this error because you are trying to return `interface{}` as concrete type `string`. If you want to return string, and you're sure that value of map is always string(then why are you using `map[string]interface{}` instead of `map[string]string`?) you can get underlying type of interface by using type assertion:

```
s, ok := v.(string)
```

Comment: Now I got it. Since the map could contain either string or anything, so it is better to return an `interface` and then the consumer of the function should figure out the type of return value whether it is a string, interface or otherwise and use accordingly?

Comment: @Volatil3 Yep, that would be good solution, to leave that to consumer